# ERROR TypeError: "values is undefined" angular 5 httpclient

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, observable, angular-httpclient

I have implemented httpclient method to integrated REST api on my angular 5 app as follows , following is login api which posts username and password and should return user data

```
let header = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Ip': this.ipAddress});
return this.http.post( this.apiUrl+'login/', JSON.stringify({access_token: accessToken}), ({headers: header})).map((user) => {
                let apiResponse = user['response'];
                let id           = apiResponse.data.id;
                let first_name   = apiResponse.data.first_name;
                let last_name    = apiResponse.data.last_name;
            } else {
                console.log(11)
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return apiResponse;
            }
```

it give me following error most of the times ( sometimes it works )

```
ERROR TypeError: "values is undefined"
```

I tried with obserables as follows but it didnt works give me other issue

```
return this.http.post<Response>( this.apiUrl+'login/', JSON.stringify({access_token: accessToken}), ({headers: header})).map((user) => {
```

Comment: 1.-map is used to transform a response, use "do" instead. 2.-when you have a Observable you must subscribe to it to make the call. 3.-else? you have no an "if"

Comment: Can you fix formatting? It looks liek you're missing `if (...) {`

Answer (score 0):

That map function should be a subscribe. Change it and log the response to keep working properly

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be in using *map* function instead of *subscribe* function. 
However, I had a similar issue where I tried to make a POST request and send some headers with it.
The cause for the issue was actually in the fact that **the value of one of the headers was undefined.**

Found an answer here: [Angular 'values is undefined' subscribing to mapped http response (request not being made?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919948/angular-values-is-undefined-subscribing-to-mapped-http-response-request-not-b)