# Angular 'values is undefined' subscribing to mapped http response (request not being made?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a simple login form component (`LoginComponent`) that calls the `submitLogin` method.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { first }  from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    returnURL: string;

    u = new FormControl('');
    p = new FormControl('');

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private auth: AuthenticationService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.returnURL = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    submitLogin(): void {
        this.auth.login(this.u.value, this.p.value).pipe(first()).subscribe(
            r => {
                if (r) {
                    console.log("LoginComponent: r:", r);
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnURL]);
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.error("LoginComponent: Error:", error);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting is getting printed as `LoginComponent: Error: TypeError: 'values' is undefined`, and it's getting printed in that error lambda.

The `AuthenticationService` looks (roughly) like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../models/user';
import { APIService } from './api.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public currentUser: Observable<User>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private api: APIService) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }
    login(u: string, p: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.api.login(u, p).pipe(map(
            r => {
                if (r && r.status === 200) {
                    this.updateCurrentUser();
                    console.log("returning true");
                    return true;
                }
                console.log("returning false");
                return false;
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

Notice that all code paths in the map lambda return a boolean value. So this map should never spit out `undefined` values. Those console logs never happen, by the way.

And my API service is responsible for making calls to a versioned API I have running. It's got a lot of unrelated stuff in it, but the relevant bits are:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class APIService {
    public API_VERSION = '1.5';

    private cookies: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    private do(method: string, path: string, data?: Object): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
        const options = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                                   'Cookie': this.cookies}),
                         observe: 'response' as 'response',
                         body: data};
        return this.http.request(method, path, options).pipe(map(r => {
            //TODO pass alerts to the alert service
            let resp = r as HttpResponse<any>;
            if ('Cookie' in resp.headers) {
                this.cookies = resp.headers['Cookie']
            }
            console.log("returning resp");
            return resp;
        }));
    }

    public login(u, p): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
        const path = '/api/'+this.API_VERSION+'/user/login';
        return this.do('post', path, {u, p});
    }
}
```

Note that again, every code path in the map lambda returns a value. Also note that `"returning resp"` never appears in the console. I also never see an HTTP request being made in the network panel. What gives? Why isn't it doing the request, and/or what could possibly be causing this error?

Comment: Where is the `values` variable located? Angular is specifically saying that that it's undefined, so at some point some method is trying to access it.
What does the `first()` method do?

Comment: `values` is something that's handled by the `rxjs` stuff on observables. I don't know how it works. `first()` is imported from `rxjs`, and its function is to emit only the first value emitted by the observable.

Comment: In your APIService, ‘login‘ calls a ‘post‘ function, what does that do? It all seems to depend on that implementation

Comment: oh, that's just a convenience function for making POST requests using that `do` method. I must've forgotten to clean that up, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stacktrace I got in the console after replicating your code led me to the 'lazyInit' function within the headers code of Angular's httpClient module (`node_modules\@angular\common\esm5\http\src\headers.js`).

In the second line of the function, it iterates over the values of the header you're submitting, and you can see the `values` variable on the third. There it gets one of the headers and accesses it's values. Next it converts it to an array, if it's a string, and then checks it's length - at this point you get the exception.

If you look at your API service, there's two headers you're submitting:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Cookie': this.cookies
```

And earlier, you define the `cookies` variable like this:

`private cookies: string;`

Since you don't assign a value, it defaults to `undefined`, which is then the value of your 'Cookie' header, which is not a string and also doesn't have a `length` property, so it's throwing an Exception.

**Solution:**

Changing the initial definition of `cookies` to

`private cookies = '';`

fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

If any `undefined` is passed to the headers to the `HTTP` call this can happen and it may cause other calls to be broken if `header` is common. Initialize the values with a default empty value. This error message is hard to debug.